# Iterate PHP Array in Form Submission

Tags: php, arrays

I have an HTML form that's submitting to a PHP script and send it as an email.
The problem I'm having is iterating the array and getting the output formatted into a table correctly.

My input fields look like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="alternate[][qty]" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="alternate[][height]" />
```

I am iterating the array like this:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['alternate']))
        {
            foreach($_POST['alternate'] as $alt)
            {
                $message .= "<tr><td>" . $alt['qty'] . "</td><td>" . $alt['height'] . "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the correct values from the array but they are not formatted correctly. I am looking for an output something like this:

123 45

but instead it breaks across two rows like this:

[image]

How can I get both values on the same line?

**EDIT:**

Using

```
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST['alternate']);
    echo '</pre>';
```

I get
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [qty] => 54
            )

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [height] => 5
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 34
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [height] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [qty] => 36
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [height] => 45
        )
    ...
)
```

which makes it look like I actually have 6 arrays...? That would explain why I'm getting each cell on a separate row, but I still don't understand how to fix it...

Comment: So that's what it *looks like*, but what does the HTML contain?

Comment: @Mr.Llama This is the generated HTML <tr><td>123</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>45</td></tr>

Comment: @mack updated my solution, take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through every element in `$_POST['alternate']` and creating a row for each iteration. There are two elements, thus two rows.

There's no need to iterate since you already know which elements you'll get:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['alternate']))
{
  $message = "<tr><td>{$_POST['alternate']['qty']}</td><td>{$_POST['alternate']['height']}</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: The 'alternates' array contains multiple items, each item has a qty and a height. The final output should show the qty and height for each array item in a single row.

Comment: If your `alternates` contains multiple items you'll probably need two `foreach` then. Do a `print_r($_POST['alternate'])` to get a hang of the structure of your `alternates` and see if you can solve it on your own. If not, come back and ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, I hope that's what you're opting for.

```
if(isset($_POST['alternate']))
{
    $message = "<tr>";
    foreach($_POST['alternate'] as $alt)
    {
        if(isset($alt['qty']))
            $message .= "<td>" . $alt['qty'] . "</td>";
        elseif(isset($alt['height']))
            $message .= "<td>" . $alt['height'] . "</td>";
    }
    $message .= "</tr>";
}
```

This gave me `<tr><td>123</td><td>45</td></tr>`.

---

### EDITED SOLUTION

This script actually takes care of `<tr>` tags inside of the loop.

```
if(isset($_POST['alternate']))
{
    foreach($_POST['alternate'] as $alt)
    {
        if(isset($alt['qty']))
            $message .= "<tr><td>" . $alt['qty'] . "</td>";
        elseif(isset($alt['height']))
            $message .= "<td>" . $alt['height'] . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Thanks @jvitasek, that does give me the values on the same line, the only problem is that the 'alternate' array contains multiple values. If I do not include the <tr> inside of the loop, all the values end up on one huge row.

Comment: @mack Do you still need the solution? I can edit it to make it so.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML actually declares separate array entries. You need to group them by defining keys for the array. Something like:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="alternate[0][qty]" />
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="alternate[0][height]" />
```

Then the next group of fields uses "1" and so on.